# Laravel and apache2: 403 forbidden

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, laravel

I am trying to deploy my Laravel app in apache2 locally, however when trying to browse to `http://myapp.localhost.com/` I am getting the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at myapp.localhost.com Port 80
```

I created `myapp.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to set up the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.localhost.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/user/projects/myapp/public"
  <Directory "/home/user/projects/myapp/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And created a symlink in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` (`sudo ln -s ../sites-available/myapp.conf`)

Also edited the `/etc/hosts` file and added:

```
127.0.0.1   myapp.localhost.com
```

Any clue why I am getting this error? I am also having the same problem when trying to deploy the application to `heroku`, which also uses `apache2`.

Comment: If needed PM me. I'll have a look to any questions you have. But your virtual host seems to be missing some options ;)

Comment: sure, I'd like you to ask you soome questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am missing the

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

in your myapp.conf. As of Apache-2.4 mod_authz_host is used and `Require`  (example  `Require all granted`) should be used.

By the way... this:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I remember from the apache as the default when using httpd.conf. Are you sure the `sites-*/*` are being used?

Comment: I added Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI and Require all granted and now it works. I am trying to access my application through my mobile phone (which is in the same network), however when browsing `myapp.localhost.com` I am not getting the page. How can I do this?

Comment: I would start by checking apache log and see if your mobile reaches your site. If it does not: router. If it does it will have a error notice.

Comment: I am not sure what I should be looking at in the log to see what you're saying. I can see a line in the `access.log` that some lines go like this `192.168.1.135 - - [16/Jan/2015:20:14:54 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; XT1032 Build/KXB21.14-L1.40) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Mobile Safari/537.36"` it says Android so it has tobe the phone

Comment: Yes it will be the phone. Means the problem is in the site itself probably and not in the network.

Comment: how is the problem in the site? it works in my machine, why wouldn't it work in the phone?

Answer (score 0):

In your VirtualHost write the DocumentRoot to point to your Laravel Application in your home directories. In addition you must add the Directory shown below, with your own path.

```
<Directory /home/john/Laravel_Projects/links/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The second step, you must go to your Laravel Project and run the following command.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
```

At the end restart your apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Never ever run this command with 777 permissions it's bad practice, Storage has sensitive file e.g oauth-private.key, oauth-public.key which a hacker can use to compromise the site. Instead run this command sudo chmod -R 775 storage bootstrap/cache